# Typo on Career's Job Posting Preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, spelling

On the job preview page, the word "looks" is spelled "loooks".

[image: Typo]

Comment: You're supposed to use #FF0000 for freehand circles.

Comment: I think this is by design. It's to make sure you loook really closely.

Comment: @Mahnax: I'm insulted that you'd assume I did otherwise. Note that the above color is #FF0000 with partial transparency ;)

Comment: @AdamRobinson Well, okay. Fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed in the next build.

Comment: -1 for not being `bydesign`.